# How to debug in the middle of a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, debugging, select

I'm debugging a SELECT query with correlated subquery that isn't returning the right results. The form of my query is, schematically

```
SELECT id, cost, country
FROM table AS table1
WHERE table1.cost =
(
    SELECT MAX(table2.cost)
    FROM table as table2
    WHERE table2.country = table1.country
)
```

I'd like to be able to pause mid-execution and see the values being compared in the WHERE statement. However a PRINT statement seems not to run if I put it as the first line of the subquery, for example. I am new to SQL and would be curious what a more experienced person considers to be the most time-efficient way to debug in such a situation.

Comment: What does `SELECT MAX(cost) FROM table as table2` return? BTW, that subquery is not correlated. It needs a WHERE clause condition referencing table1.

Comment: There is nothing to debug here, I don't know what is the better way , but to see the comparison every cost of `table1` just take the sub query and put it as a column in the select clause and run the statement without `where` clause

Comment: There was an issue with the example, I just fixed it, thanks for pointing that out. But I am not asking in particular about the query I wrote here, I'm just wondering if it is possible, in general, to pause in the middle of a subquery to see the values that a particular variable takes, in order to debug. Or if this isn't possible, is there any better way to debug other than writing out subsets of the code to see if they are each working properly?

Comment: What is the *right result*? Currently you get the row(s) with the maximum cost per country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not support what you want want to do.

It is very important to remember that SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  A SQL query describes the result set being produced.  It does *not* specify the specific actions being taken.

If you want to know what the result of the subquery is, then run that as a separate query.

Comment: In practice, though, a series of procedures are of course executed "under the hood" to achieve the desired output. So in that regard, this remained a hypothetical possibility - but it is good to know that I should not look further for such a feature. Thank you for the help.